# How to use an xpath on a file content loaded via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Typical case:

```
       $.ajax({
            url: schedule.link,
            context: document.body
        }).done(function(data) {
            // tutt ok, quindi scrivo il file
            console.log (data);
        }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorDescription ) {
            // segnalo il problema
            logga("Error " + error.description);
        });
```

**How to use xPath on `data` received via ajax ?**

I need to simply get `//ul.result` as xpath

Comment: You could use document.evaluate https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

Comment: please, make me an example ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it as follow (if you're using jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
        url: schedule.link,
        context: document.body
    }).success(function(data) {
        // gives you the html inside the matching expression
        alert($('xpathexpr', data).html());
    }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorDescription ) {
        // segnalo il problema
        logga("Error " + error.description);
    });
```